# SettingWithCopyWarning, even when using loc (?)

Tags: python, pandas

I get `SettingWithCopyWarning` errors in cases where I would not expect them:

```
N.In <38>: # Column B does not exist yet
N.In <39>: df['B'] = df['A']/25
N.In <40>: df['B'] = df['A']/50

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:389: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
  self.obj[item] = s
```

and

```
N.In <41>: df.loc[:,'B'] = df['A']/50

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:389: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
  self.obj[item] = s
```

Why does it happen in case 1 and 2?

Comment: you need to show code before this (as much as u can)

Comment: Thanks @Jeff I updated the OP with a few previous lines

Comment: Add before that; u r doing an operation inplace previously

Comment: I've never understood why this needs to be so complicated and therefore created a simpler data table library, *tabel* https://github.com/BastiaanBergman/tabel. For simple use cases it's faster as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In case 1, `df['A']` creates a copy of `df`. As explained by the [Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), this can lead to unexpected results when chaining, thus a warning is raised. Case 2 looks correct, but false positives are possible:

> Warning: The chained assignment warnings / exceptions are aiming to
>   inform the user of a possibly invalid assignment. There may be false
>   positives; situations where a chained assignment is inadvertantly
>   reported.

To turn off `SettingWithCopyWarning` for a single dataframe, use

```
df.is_copy = False
```

To turn off chained assignment warnings altogether, use

```
options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Comment: Use the following like to disable the warning:

`pd.set_option('chained_assignment',None)`

Answer (score 8):

Another solution that should suppress the warning:

```
df = df.copy()
df['B'] = df['A']/25
df['B'] = df['A']/50
```

Comment: This does indeed work. Not fully understand if this is now faster or more memory consuming. I don't know the impact of the copy() command. Since in fact the copy is reassign again to df.. It looks like nothing is changed at the end.