# How to select a list of rows by name in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, select, dataframe

I am trying to extract rows from a Pandas dataframe using a list of row names, but it can't be done. Here is an example

```
# df
    alleles  chrom  pos strand  assembly#  center  protLSID  assayLSID  
rs#
TP3      A/C      0    3      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP7      A/T      0    7      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP12     T/A      0   12      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP15     C/A      0   15      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP18     C/T      0   18      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN

test = ['TP3','TP12','TP18']

df.select(test)
```

This is what I was trying to do with just element of the list and I am getting this error `TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `df.select()` is [deprecated in favor of `df.loc()` since 0.21](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select.html#pandas.DataFrame.select), and also it was for selecting rows(/columns) based on a condition function. Not for simple indexing by list of (row/column-)names.

Comment: Very similar to [How are iloc and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `df.loc[['TP3','TP12','TP18']]`

Here is a small example:

```
In [26]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [3,4,5], "c": [5,6,7]})

In [27]: df.index = ["x", "y", "z"]

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
   a  b  c
x  1  3  5
y  2  4  6
z  3  5  7

[3 rows x 3 columns]

In [29]: df.loc[["x", "y"]]
Out[29]: 
   a  b  c
x  1  3  5
y  2  4  6

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 ways to access the element of of a pandas dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=(10,10)),columns= list('PQRSTUVWXY'),index= list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))
```

Using `df[['P','Q']]` you can only access the columns of the dataframe. You can use the `dataframe.loc[]` (stands for location) or `dataframe.iloc[]` (stands for index location) numpy style slicing of the dataframe.

```
df.loc[:,['P','Q']]
```

Above will give you columns named by 'P' and 'Q'.

```
df.loc[['A','B'],:]
```

Above will return rows with keys 'A' and 'B'.

You can also use number based slicing using `iloc` method.

```
df.iloc[:,[1,2]]
```

This will return columns numbered by 1 and 2.
While,

```
df.iloc[[1,2],:]
```

will return rows 1st and 2nd.
You can access any specific element by

```
df.iloc[1,2]
```

or,

```
df.loc['A','Q']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can select the rows by position:

```
df.iloc[[0,2,4], :]
```

Comment: The OP asked about a list of row names, not numerical indices. In general `df.iloc()` and numeric indices are less preferred to row-names.

Comment: @smci Yeah, that's a valid point. The OP did say "by name". You're right.