# How to select the last column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have done some searching for the answer to this question, but all I can figure out is this:

```
df[df.columns[len(df.columns)-1]]
```

which to me seems unweildy, and un-pythonic (and slow?).

What is the easiest way to select the data for the last column in a pandas dataframe without specifying the name of the column?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Use iloc and select all rows (`:`) against the last column (`-1`):

```
df.iloc[:,-1:]
```

Comment: I tried to do that and got an error saying "too many indexers"

Comment: @user287474 that'll happen if you're operating over a `Series` - make sure you're using a `DataFrame`

Answer (score 49):

Somewhat similar to your original attempt, but more Pythonic, is to use Python's standard negative-indexing convention to count backwards from the end:

```
df[df.columns[-1]]
```

Comment: will this work? ```df[df.columns[-1] >= 10]``` it gives me "not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

Comment: @Mike_Leigh your comparison shouldn’t be happening inside the bracket

Answer (score 31):

These are few things which will help you in understanding everything... using iloc

In iloc, [initial row:ending row, initial column:ending column]

case 1: if you want only last column --- `df.iloc[:,-1] & df.iloc[:,-1:]`
this means that you want only the last column...

case 2: if you want all columns and all rows except the last column --- `df.iloc[:,:-1]`
this means that you want all columns and all rows except the last column...

case 3: if you want only last row --- `df.iloc[-1:,:] & df.iloc[-1,:]` 
this means that you want only the last row...

case 4: if you want all columns and all rows except the last row --- `df.iloc[:-1,:]`
this means that you want all columns and all rows except the last column...

case 5: if you want all columns and all rows except the last row and last column --- `df.iloc[:-1,:-1]`
this means that you want all columns and all rows except the last column and last row...

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to @Anshul Singh Suryan's answer:

When we split the dataframe to just get the last column:

If we split like:

`y = df.iloc[:,-1:] - y` remains a `dataframe`

However, if we split like

`y = df.iloc[:,-1] - y` becomes a `Series`.

This is a notable difference that I've found in the two approaches. If you don't care about the resultant type, you can use either of the two. Otherwise you need to take care of the above findings.

This is applicable for any number of rows you want to extract and not just the last row.
For example, if you want last `n` number of rows of a dataframe, where n is  any integer less than or equal to the number of columns present in the dataframe, then you can easily do the following:

```
y = df.iloc[:,n:]
```

Replace `n` by the number of columns you want. Same is true for rows as well.

Answer (score 7):

The question is: how to select the last column of a dataframe ?
Appart @piRSquared, none answer the question.

the simplest way to get a dataframe with the last column is:

```
df.iloc[ :, -1:]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.T.iloc[-1]
```

---

```
df.T.tail(1)
```

---

```
pd.Series(df.values[:, -1], name=df.columns[-1])
```

Comment: I don't see any value of building the Series explicitly out of the numpy values extraction compared to a direct call to iloc

Comment: @Boud, There are many ways to do this.  I was simply trying to dump a bunch down.  Admittedly, the third option is the weakest.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do it. I think maybe a little more general:

```
df.ix[:,-1]
```

Comment: In this case, your answer is not recommended because the question asks explicitly for the *last* column which is index location based. `ix` mixes label and index location accessor. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation) for more.

Comment: Indeed, in addition, `ix` is deprecated by now.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use [`take`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.take.html):

```
df.take([-1], axis=1)
```