# How to get a value from a cell of a dataframe by position or label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read the questions ["How to get a value from a cell of a dataframe?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16729574/778533) and ["How to select the last column of dataframe"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40144769/778533). I am a bit confused as to what is the accepted method in 2018 for getting a value from the cell of a pandas dataframe, as [`get_value`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get_value.html) has been deprecated and the documentation on [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) is somewhat sparse. I want to select the row by label and the column by position/integer. Is my method below in which I use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) the accepted approach in 2018? I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import string
import csv
import io

## Make a table with random column labels and rows in random order.
s = '\n'.join((
    ## Separate columns by comma.
    ','.join((
        ## Join letters without a separator.
        ''.join((
            ## Randomly choose 3 characters for the labels from ascii_letters.
            random.choice(
                string.ascii_letters) for i in range(3))) for j in range(3))),
    ## Insert a header to distinguish rows with identical index keys x and y.
    '"Header I, II and III"',
    ## Randomly shuffle the rows under the first header.
    '\n'.join(random.sample(('x,0,1', 'y,2,3',), 2)),
    ## Insert a header to distinguish rows with identical index keys x and y.
    '"Header IV, V and VI"',
    ## Randomly shuffle the rows under the second header.
    '\n'.join(random.sample(('x,4,5', 'y,6,7'), 2)),
    ))

def preprocess(s):
    header = ''
    for l in csv.reader(io.StringIO(s)):
        if len(l) == 1:
            header = l[0]
            continue
        ## Append the header to distinguish identical labels x and y.
        l[0] = header + '; ' + l[0]
        yield l

print(s, end='\n\n')
## Preprocess the string to avoid duplicate row index keys x and y.
df = pd.DataFrame(preprocess(s))
print(df, end='\n\n')
## Set the index to be that of the first column.
df = df.set_index(0)
## First select the column by index using iloc
## and then select the relevant row by index label.
value = df.iloc[:,-1]['Header I, II and III; x']
print(value)
```

It generates a string `s` looking like this:

```
YuT,Uva,AsE
"Header I, II and III"
y,2,3
x,0,1
"Header IV, V and VI"
y,6,7
x,4,5
```

Which is converted to a dataframe by the function `preprocess` looking like this:

```
                         0    1    2
0                    ; YuT  Uva  AsE
1  Header I, II and III; y    2    3
2  Header I, II and III; x    0    1
3   Header IV, V and VI; y    6    7
4   Header IV, V and VI; x    4    5
```

It is the value (the integer 1) from the last column of the row with the label `Header I, II and III; x`, which I'm interested in. Is this the correct approach in 2018?

```
value = df.iloc[:,-1]['Header I, II and III; x']
```

I just read some very interesting questions ["Loc vs. iloc vs. ix vs. at vs. iat?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/loc-vs-iloc-vs-ix-vs-at-vs-iat) from February 2015 and ["pandas iloc vs ix vs loc explanation?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31593201/778533) from July 2015. It would be great, if I could do something like this, but I can't:

```
value = df.at['Header I, II and III; x', -1]
value = df['Header I, II and III; x'][-1]
```

Comment: `df.iat[2, -1]` Would be the correct approach.

Comment: Or, `df.at['Header I, II and III; x', 2]`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks. `Header I, II and III; x` however is not always at the second row. It can be randomly shuffled around.

Comment: In that case, `at` would be better. See my second comment.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ OK, but what if the number of columns is also random and I want the last column and not the second column? Sorry, I should have been more explicit.

Comment: If it's the last column, you can use `df.at['Header I, II and III; x', df.columns[-1]]`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Great! Can you leave that as an answer? Can you perhaps elaborate in your answer, why `at` is to prefer over `iloc` as in my example? Would there ever be a scenario in which `df.columns[-1]` is slow? Thanks!

Comment: To answer your last question, no, `df.columns` is a list/array, and they support random access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing's first. `ix` is deprecated, but `ix` allowed you to mix labels and indexers, and made a lot of guesses about what it was passed.

In today's day and age (with the current stable release being `v0.22`), `ix` is deprecated, so stick to explicit label or positional based indexers: `loc` for label based slicing, `iloc` for index based slicing; `at` for label based item access, and `iat` for index based item access.

If you know what your labels are, use `at` to access a single item -

```
df.at['Header I, II and III; x', df.columns[-1]]
```

If you know the position, use `iat` -

```
df.iat[2, -1]
```

In general, use `*at` when you want to access a single element, and `*loc` when you want to access a row/column slice.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wish the documentation explained this.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer too :-)

Answer (score 1):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48247245/778533) definitely works:

```
value = df.at['Header I, II and III; x', df.columns[-1]]
```

For those like myself that like old-fashioned dictionaries it is also possible to do the following, if the dataframe does not contain duplicate row labels, which prevents the `transpose` from working:

```
d = df.transpose().to_dict('list')
value = d['Header I, II and III; x'][-1]
```