# how to get last column of pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count frequencies of an array.
I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144769/how-to-select-the-last-column-of-dataframe), I am using DataFrame and get a series.

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 4])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
>>> b = df.groupby('a').size()
>>> b
a
0    2
1    4
2    2
4    1
5    1
dtype: int64
>>> b.iloc[:,-1]
```

when i try to get the last column, i got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/Users/pan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1472, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)   File "/Users/pan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2013, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)   File "/Users/pan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 220, in _has_valid_tuple
    raise IndexingError('Too many indexers') pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

how to get the last column of `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is output of [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) is `Series`, and `Series` have no columns, so is possible get last value only:

```
b.iloc[-1]
```

If use:

```
b.iloc[:,-1]
```

it return last column in `Dataframe`.

Here `:` means all rows and `-1` in second position last column.

So if create `DataFrame` from `Series`:

```
b1 = df.groupby('a').size().reset_index(name='count')
```

it working like expected.

Answer (score 2):

Since `pandas.Series` is a

> One-dimensional ndarray with axis labels

If you want to get just the frequencies column, i.e. the values of 
your series, use:

```
b.tolist()
```

or, alternatively:

```
b.to_dict()
```

to keep both labels and frequencies.

P.S:

For your specific task consider also `collections` package:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = [1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 4]
>>> c = Counter(a)
>>> list(c.values())
[2, 4, 2, 1, 1]
```