# Get last column of pandas dataframes using python

Tags: python, pandas

How do you get the last (or "nth") column in a dataFrame?

I tried several different articles such as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547287/how-to-get-last-column-of-pandas-series) and [2](https://yoursdata.net/beginners-guide-selections-pandas-dataframe/).

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

col=df.iloc[:,0] #returns Index([], dtype='object')
col2=df.iloc[:,-1] #returns the whole dataframe
col3=df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('c')] #returns Index([], dtype='object')
```

The commented out parts after the code is what I am getting after a print. Most of the time I am getting things like "returns Index([], dtype='object')"

Here is what df prints:

```
     date     open     high      low    close
0     0   2019-07-09 09:20:10  296.235  296.245  296...         
1     1   2019-07-09 09:20:15  296.245  296.245  296...         
2     2   2019-07-09 09:20:20  296.235  296.245  296...         
3     3   2019-07-09 09:20:25  296.235  296.275  296...
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `df`?

Comment: yes. just edited it in.

Comment: Try using col = df.iloc[ :  , df.shape[1]-1]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Given this data, when I run the commands you provided, I get in order: `0    2019-07-09\1    2019-07-09...`, `0    296\1    296...`,`Index(['close'], dtype='object')`. You might check `df.shape`, `df.head()`, and `df.info()` right after your `read_csv` command to ensure that the data is being read the way you think it is

Comment: Maybe (I'm not sure here) you got a multi-index or smh. Can you check your df.columns?

Comment: I tried your code and it works as intended. May be something wrong with the data imported

Answer (score 0):

`df.iloc` is able to refer to both rows and columns. If you only input one integer, it will automatically refer to a row. You can mix the indexer types for the index and columns. Use `:` to select the entire axis.

`df.iloc[:,-1:]` will print out all of the final column.

Comment: This is what the user already did and it did not return the expected result, as shown in the given code and the linked answers. `df.iloc[:,-1:]` is equivalent to `df.iloc[:,-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Try printing the shape of the data frame. The column was 1 in my case cause I did not split the data correctly using delimiter. Once I split the data correctly, the issue was resolved and df.iloc[:,-1:] worked.

Comment: Hi, according to the print in the question, dataframe length is not the issue here. Also what's with using a range (`iloc[:,-1:]`) instead of `.iloc[:,-1]` when pointing to a  single row?