# how to get access of last column of a dataframe by using .loc[]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is it possible to get access of last column of a data frame and last row of a data frame by using

```
.loc[]
```

I saw this link

```
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144769/how-to-select-the-last-column-of-dataframe
```

but in this discussion no one spoke about loc .  I would be appreciate if someone helps me to to solve this problem. thanks a lot.

Comment: why not use `.iloc` as per the link you shared? with `.loc` you will have to specify the index / column, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different

if you know the index of the last row / column name of the last column, then use `.loc`. otherwise `.iloc` lets you select them by positional order

Answer (score 0):

`
df_test = pd.DataFrame([2012, 2015, 2010], columns=['start_date'])

df_test['end_date'] = [2014, 2017, 2020]

last_index = list(df_test.index)[-1]

last_col = list(df_test.columns)[-1]

df_test.loc[last_index, last_col]
`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vznk.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:
df.iloc[-1:,-1:]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That is what **iloc** is made for

The **loc** method locates data by label. The **iloc** method locates data by integer index. If no column names are defined, this would be the easiest way:

```
data = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.iloc[-1,:]

output:
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    3
4    3
```

Last row would be accordingly:

```
df.iloc[:,-1]

output:
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

If you still want to use **loc**, the last column you wish to refer to needs a name since location by interger indexing is not possible.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first_column': [50, 60], 'last_column': [100, 120]})

df.loc[:]['last_column']

output:
0    100
1    120
```