# How to convert the last column output labels of excel dataset into categories and then use these labels into training and testing of model`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx') 
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df['last_column'] = df['last_column'].map({'not fire':0, 'fire':1})
```

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

4 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'last_column'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'last_column'
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40144839/11360318

Comment: Or use `df.iloc[:, -1]` to access the last column