# ix is not referring the index as required

Tags: python, pandas

In [pandas iloc vs ix vs loc explanation, how are they different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation), it mentions that:`ix` usually tries to behave like `loc` but falls back to behaving like `iloc` if the label is not in the index.

For the example below, when I use ix[0], it does not work, what happened?

[image]

**Note**: As of Pandas v0.20, `.ix` [indexer is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) in favour of `.iloc` / `.loc`.

Answer (score 3):

Short explanation

Consider dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4),
    list('wxyz'), list('abcd'))

    a   b   c   d
w   0   1   2   3
x   4   5   6   7
y   8   9  10  11
z  12  13  14  15
```

- `iloc` is ordinal position based indexing

  ```
  df.iloc[[0, 3], [1, 2]]

      b   c
  w   1   2
  z  13  14
  ```
- `loc` is label based indexing

  ```
  df.loc[['z', 'x'], ['b', 'c']]

      b   c
  z  13  14
  x   5   6
  ```
- `ix` tries to be smart and figure out what you need but is sometimes confusing and most importantly will be phased out and should not be used!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing):

> **ix** supports mixed integer and label based access. It is primarily label based, but will fall back to integer positional access unless the corresponding axis is of integer type. **.ix** is the most general and will support any of the inputs in **.loc** and **.iloc**. **.ix** also supports floating point label schemes. **.ix** is exceptionally useful when dealing with mixed positional and label based hierarchical indexes.
>
> However, when an **axis is integer based**, ONLY **label based access** and not positional access is supported. Thus, in such cases, it’s usually better to be explicit and use **.iloc** or **.loc**.