# python iloc and loc function generating different behavior in selecting rows

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I was playing around with pandas and find the following feature is kind of strange.

For example, we have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"egg":[47,50,89],"salt":[12.0,19.0,np.nan],"spam":[17,31,72]})
prinf(df,'\n')
print(df.iloc[0:2,0:3],'\n')
print(df.loc[0:2,"egg":"spam"],'\n')
```

[image]

So if I use `.iloc`, then for rows the row with index 2 is not selected. But if I use `.loc`, same command for selecting the rows, here the row with index 2 is selected.

Can someone explain why? This behavior is very unnatural.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation

Comment: This is basically because `.loc` is label based. It is designed for operations like `df.loc['Argentina':'France']` (where you would expect France to be included). For consistency, it behaves the same way with numbers.