# Python Pandas - find consecutive group with max aggregate values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, grouping

I have a data frame with datetimes and integers

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['dt'] = pd.date_range("2017-01-01 12:00", "2017-01-01 12:30", freq="1min")
df['val'] = np.random.choice(xrange(1, 100), df.shape[0])
```

Gives me

```
                    dt  val
0  2017-01-01 12:00:00   33
1  2017-01-01 12:01:00   42
2  2017-01-01 12:02:00   44
3  2017-01-01 12:03:00    6
4  2017-01-01 12:04:00   70
5  2017-01-01 12:05:00   94*
6  2017-01-01 12:06:00   42*
7  2017-01-01 12:07:00   97*
8  2017-01-01 12:08:00   12
9  2017-01-01 12:09:00   11
10 2017-01-01 12:10:00   66
11 2017-01-01 12:11:00   71
12 2017-01-01 12:12:00   25
13 2017-01-01 12:13:00   23
14 2017-01-01 12:14:00   39
15 2017-01-01 12:15:00   25
```

How can I find which `N`-minute group of *consecutive* `dt` gives me the maximum sum of `val`?

In this case, if `N=3`, then the result should be:

```
                    dt  val
5  2017-01-01 12:05:00   94
6  2017-01-01 12:06:00   42
7  2017-01-01 12:07:00   97
```

(marked with stars above)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`np.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) to get the correct starting index and go from there.

```
def cons_max(df, N):
    max_loc = np.convolve(df.val, np.ones(N, dtype=int), mode='valid').argmax()
    return df.loc[max_loc:max_loc+N-1]
```

**Demo**

```
>>> cons_max(df, 3)
                   dt  val
5 2017-01-01 12:05:00   94
6 2017-01-01 12:06:00   42
7 2017-01-01 12:07:00   97

>>> cons_max(df, 5)
                   dt  val
4 2017-01-01 12:04:00   70
5 2017-01-01 12:05:00   94
6 2017-01-01 12:06:00   42
7 2017-01-01 12:07:00   97
8 2017-01-01 12:08:00   12
```

This works be effectively "sliding" the kernel (array of ones) across our input and multiply-accumulating the elements in our window of size `N` together.

Comment: thanks. This works quite well for parameterizing `N`

Comment: that's actually a very interesting way to do it... could be extended lots of ways... thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: if df.val is a float instead of an int, must np.ones(3,dtype=float) or is an int still OK?

Comment: @philshem Yes, `int` is still fine - those are just our multipliers.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Credit to some cookbook I can't recall where I learnt about `convolve`, but you're welcome!

Comment: FWIW - in my real code, convolve() doesn't work with my datetime (`TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'`) but does work with `df.index` instead of `df.val`

Comment: @philshem Because a summing op on datetimes is undefined - use the index!

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`rolling/sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [`np.nanargmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanargmax.html) to find the index associated with the first occurrence of the maximum value:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': ['2017-01-01 12:00:00', '2017-01-01 12:01:00', '2017-01-01 12:02:00', '2017-01-01 12:03:00', '2017-01-01 12:04:00', '2017-01-01 12:05:00', '2017-01-01 12:06:00', '2017-01-01 12:07:00', '2017-01-01 12:08:00', '2017-01-01 12:09:00', '2017-01-01 12:10:00', '2017-01-01 12:11:00', '2017-01-01 12:12:00', '2017-01-01 12:13:00', '2017-01-01 12:14:00', '2017-01-01 12:15:00'], 'val': [33, 42, 44, 6, 70, 94, 42, 97, 12, 11, 66, 71, 25, 23, 39, 25]})
df.index = df.index*10

N = 3
idx = df['val'].rolling(window=N).sum()
i = np.nanargmax(idx) + 1
print(df.iloc[i-N : i])
```

prints

```
                     dt  val
50  2017-01-01 12:05:00   94
60  2017-01-01 12:06:00   42
70  2017-01-01 12:07:00   97
```

[`iloc` uses ordinal indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31593712/190597). `loc` uses label-based indexing. Provided that
both `i-N` and `i` are valid indices, `df.iloc[i-N : i]` will grab a window
(sub-DataFrame) of length `N`. In contrast, `df.loc[i-N, i]` will only grab a
window of length `N` if the index uses consecutive integers. The example above
shows a DataFrame where `df.loc` would not work since `df.index` has
non-consecutive integer values.

Comment: FWIW - I can't get `rolling()` to work with either my timestamp (`ops for Rolling for this dtype datetime64[ns] are not implemented`) or my index (`'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'rolling'`).

Comment: `rolling` does not work with `datetime64`s because (for example) summing `datetime64`s is not defined. If you wish to use `rolling` on an integer-valued index, you could use `df.index.to_series().rolling(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

For simple single values, you can use something like:

```
df['total'] = df.val + df.val.shift(-1) + df.val.shift(-2)
first = df.dropna().sort('total').index[-1]
df.iloc[first:first+3]
```

Not sure how to generalize this... with most things pandas, there is probably an easier way, but this does work.

Edit: After a little more work, it looks like rolling is what you want:

```
last = df.val.rolling(3).sum().dropna().sort_values().index[-1]
```

This is a slightly different, in that the index you get here is the *end*, so after doing the above you want to do

```
df.iloc[last-2:last+1]
```

I think that could be generalized.

Comment: good idea. Is there a way to parameterize the first line, in the case that I wanted N=100 instead of N=3?