# Pandas: find groups by index if consecutively numbered

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a list of tuples with start and end values (i.e. rows) from a df2 dataframe looking over the index (the first or zero column df2[0]). df2 example:

```
COL0  COL1 COL2
  4    x    y    # start 'tuple x' of COL1
  5    i    j
  6    n    m    # end 'tuple n'
 14    f    a    # start 'tuple f'
 15    e    b    # end 'tuple e'
 ...
```

So COL0 consecutive values will form a group. If the next row is not consecutive (e.g. 6-14) then a new group starts. A selection could be the following:

```
Crit_a = df2[0][0] + 1 == df2[0][1]
```

As output, I am looking for a new df3 with per row the following:

```
COL0  COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 ...
  4    x    y    n    m   # start values and end values of COL1 and COL2
 14    f    a    e    b
```

I was looking at SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308197/python-pandas-find-consecutive-group-with-max-aggregate-values) and other locations. 
Thank you for you suggestions.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: @Allen: I have added the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly your desired output, but perhaps more intuitive?

I create a column named `group_no` to label the consecutive values from `COL0`.  I differenced the columns, located values where this difference was not one, and then did a cumsum on the result.  The first element is ambiguous (it is NaN when differenced, so I check if its value plus one equals the second value.  If so, the first value is continuous and assigned a value of 1.  If not, it is not continuous and assigned a value of 0.

```
df = df.assign(group_no = (df.COL0.diff() != 1).cumsum())
df.group_no.iat[0] = 1 if df.COL0.iat[0] + 1 == df.COL0.iat[1] else 0
df_new = df.groupby('group_no').agg(
    {'COL0': ['first'], 
     'COL1': ['first', 'last'], 
     'COL2': ['first', 'last']})
>>> df_new
          COL2       COL0  COL1     
         first last first first last
group_no                            
1            y    m     4     x    n
2            a    b    14     f    e
```

The `agg` function takes a dictionary, so the resulting order of the columns can be arbitrary.  To order the resulting columns, you could do it explicitly, e.g.:

```
df_new[[('COL0', 'first'),
        ('COL1', 'first'),
        ('COL1', 'last'),
        ('COL2', 'first'),
        ('COL2', 'last')]]
```

This may also work:

```
n = 3  # First three columns of original dataframe.
df_new.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[df.columns[:n], :]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. What would be the best way to order columns of df_new, as currently they are not ordered?

Comment: Thank you for the update on ordering: however, after applying df_new[[('COL0', 'first'), ('COL1', 'first'), etc.]] following agg function, the columns remain unordered?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'applying'?  You are explicitly selecting the columns in the order you choose.

Answer (score 1):

First create a group key for rows belonging to the same group.

```
df['COL0'] = \
    (df.COL0.rolling(2,min_periods=1)
        .apply(lambda x: x[-1] if int(x[-1]-x[0])!=1 else np.nan)
        .ffill()
    )
```

Then group by the key and find the start and end row and expand them as columns. Finally rename the columns.

```
df2 = \
    (df[['COL1','COL2']].groupby(df.COL0)
        .apply(lambda x: np.array([x.iloc[0],x.iloc[-1]]).flatten())
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .rename_axis(lambda x: 'COL'+str(x+1),axis=1)
    )


df2
Out[178]: 
     COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
COL0                    
4.0     x    y    n    m
14.0    f    a    e    b
```