# Data Slicing Throwing out of bound error

Tags: dataset, slice

I was trying to assign Y axis to my DataSet:

```
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 17].values
```

When tried this command I was getting the following error:

> single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Answer (score 0):

The `DataFrame.iloc` works based on the integer positioning so you have to provide values not more than the number of rows and columns in your `DataFrame` or dataset. In your case, the `dataset.iloc[:,17]` will fetch all the rows and the first 17 columns providing a matrix of `rows*17` size. If you want only the columns then use `dataset.iloc[:17]` and this will fetch the first 17 columns. Make sure your dataset has 17 or more columns or it will show `Out-of-bounds` error.

For details refer this answer.
[pandas iloc vs ix vs loc explanation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation)

Comment: It worked. Thank you Mano. I have one more question shall I post here

Comment: Yes sure if this is related to the same topic you can edit the question here, else you can post it as a new question.

Comment: Kindly mark this as your answer since it has solved your issue.

Comment: Hey Mano, 
i have posted a question in the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864728/pivot-in-python
Can you help me in solving htis