# Python Difference between iloc indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, ipython

Newbie here.

Im trying to learn Python and work with datasets, ive kinda got thrown into the deep end at work. The language is clearly very powerful but very different to anything else ive experienced before.

I need some clarity / help / explanation on the following please.

**Partial Algo code**

```
history = data.history(context.stock_list, fields="price", bar_count=300, frequency="1d")
hs = h.iloc[-20:]
p = h.iloc[-1]
```

**What is Difference Between 3 Variables Shown?**

```
hs1 = history.iloc[:20]   
hs2 = history.iloc[20:]
hs3 = history.iloc[-20]
```

`history` creates a data sets of 4 asset prices, as can be seen from image under "additional info"

Ive researched and learned data `iloc` is a [pandas indexing and referencing function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

However what I do not understand is the `[:20]`, `[20:]`, `[-20]` indexes(?) attached to `iloc` function in the 3 example variables shown above

**Questions**

- `hs1 = history.iloc[:20]`,  According to my research following [python programming tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/dataset-data-analysis-python-pandas-tutorial/?completed=/input-output-data-analysis-python-pandas-tutorial/) on pandas dataframe `hs1 = history.iloc[:20]` singles out deletes the first 20 columns within the dataframe, is this correct?
- `hs2 = history.iloc[:20]`  What is difference to above variable?
- `hs3 = history.iloc[-20]` Why a minus `-` and no `:` inside the index?

**Additional Info**

History variable creates dataset of 3 assets

[image]

Hope this makes sense, please comment if you need any additional info any help and advice much appreciated.

Comment: This is basic indexing in python. I find it hard to believe that you are being made to develop products in a language you don't even know, without at least first pointing you to basic documentation and references. Wow, that's harsh.

Comment: As a favour, I've closed this question as a duplicate of a canonical question on the topic of slicing. Read that and understand how slicing works. Once you have understood basic slicing, it becomes easy to apply the concept to dataframes - `iloc` is just a convenience function for row/column slicing by index.

Comment: @COLDSPEED yeah it sucks but it is what it is, my job is on the line here so kinda stressed. To make it worse I come from the PHP world ugh. Thanks for the link, that does help a lot, reading through it now. Unfortunately I do not have much time to "play around with code" and test / explore different scenarios. Allow me to be a bit cheeky may I ask a huge favor from you -- would you be so kind to just shortly summarize / explain the different scenarios specific to my question?

Comment: Well, if you ask me so nicely, how can I refuse? Give me a bit.

Comment: Understanding code and functions is one thing, but if you have a more specific question on how to apply a particular operation on your data, you could open a new question. You should provide some sample data and expected output along with a brief description of what you want to achieve.  Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), it gives you a good idea of what is expected in a good pandas "How do I...?" question.

Comment: hey dont feel so bad :)many probably have same problem.  the number of times i put in **li = [1,2,3]** and use the interpreter to play w indices like yours is a bit humbling. slicing syntax is powerful but it never seems to stick long in my head :(

Comment: @Marilee *coming from* PHP is not a sin - quite possibly even an act of repentance. *Returning to* PHP on the other hand is the one that Dante forgot from the list of eight deadly vices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before beginning anything else, I recommend reading [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) to get a first class insight on how python's slicing notation works. In particular, look at the different slice modes available to you:

> ```
> a[start:end] # items start through end-1
> a[start:]    # items start through the rest of the array
> a[:end]      # items from the beginning through end-1
> a[:]         # a copy of the whole array
> ```

- `a[start:end]` returns a sub-slice from index `start` (inclusive) to `end - 1`

  ```
  >>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  >>> lst[2:5]
  [3, 4, 5]
  ```
- `a[start:]` returns a sub-slice from `start` till the *end of the list*.

  ```
  >>> lst[5:]
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  ```
- `a[:end]` returns a sub-slice from the *beginning of the list* till `end - 1`.

  ```
  >>> lst[:5]
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  ```
- `a[:]` just returns a new copy of the same list.

  ```
  >>> lst[:]
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  ```

Understand this, and you've understood dataframe indexing.

---

As I've already mentioned, `iloc` is used to select dataframe subslices by their *index*, and the same rules apply. Here's the documentation:

> ## `DataFrame.iloc`
>
> Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position.
>
> `.iloc[]` is primarily integer position based (from `0` to `length-1`
>   of the axis), but may also be used with a boolean array.

It's a bit much to take in, but the pandas [cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position) makes it simple. The basic syntax is:

```
df.iloc[x, y]
```

Where `x` is the row index/slice and `y` is the column index/slice. If the second argument is omitted, row slicing is assumed. In your case, you have:

- `history.iloc[:20]` which returns the first 20 rows.
- `history.iloc[20:]` which returns everything *after* the first 20 rows.
- `history.iloc[-20]`, which is interpreted as `history.iloc[len(history) - 20]` which is the 20th row from the *end* (negative indices specify indexing from the end).

Consider a dataframe:

```
df

   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
9  9
```

Here are the different slice modes in action.

```
df.iloc[:5]

   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

```
df.iloc[5:]

   A
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
9  9
```

```
df.iloc[-5]

A    5
Name: 5, dtype: int64
```

---

**References**

- [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)
- [Indexing in Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position)
- [pandas iloc vs ix vs loc explanation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation)

Comment: I get it now, its actually kind of simple. Just a very different syntax. Thank you so much for your time and effort...appreciate it more than you realize! Feel like I owe you.something, stay awesome :)

Comment: @Marilee Just super glad to know it helped. If you've any more questions, feel free to ping me, here, or at my email (it's in my bio). Cheers.