# Pandas Dataframe Slice using iloc or ix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a better way to separate the first half of my dataframe which has a variable number of columns.  I have tried using both the iloc and ix methods, but effectively I am writing the following for many dataframes.  Is there a better way to shorthand this?

```
df.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]] #df.ix works this way as well
```

What I'd like to do is below...

```
df.iloc[:, [0:df.shape[1]/2] #this will allow column number flexibility
```

Do any of you have an idea of a good workaround for this?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. There is a syntax error there but other than that `df.iloc[:, :df.shape[1]/2]` should be valid?

Comment: `df.iloc[:, 0:int(df.shape[1]/2)]`

Comment: Do not use .ix it is deprecated. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46915810/6361531)

Comment: @Wen, thanks, that seemed to fix it.  What made you think to use the int()? Another thing I just learned is that df.iloc[:, [0:int(df.shape[1]/2]] doesn't work either.  Ayhan, thanks for noticing the syntax error.

Comment: @TylerRussell int divided will return the float , then you are using the position selection , which is require int

Comment: @Wen, thanks so much!  That makes sense.  Appreciate your quick replies.  It was driving me insane yesterday.

Comment: @TylerRussell Yw~ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Scott mentioned in his comment, do not use `ix` because it is deprecated. Although `ix` works for now, it may not in the future, use `iloc` instead.

However, try using [`array_split()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) from numpy. It is very readable. This will split the dataframe in half evenly (`array_split` will allow an uneven number and return as close to half as possible):

```
import numpy as np

df_split = np.array_split(df, 2)
# This will return a list of dataframes.
# if you need single datframes you could always use df_split[0] for first half
# and df_split[1] for other half
```

If you needed to split the columns as well you could also do:

```
df_split = np.array_split(df.columns, 2) # <--- Notice the df.columns in the argument
first_half = df[df_split[0].tolist()]
second_half = df[df_split[1].tolist()]
```