# Why NaN appears in part of pd data output?

Tags: pandas, nan

After my data read in, df.head() showes everything OK. 
But df1 shows some NaN. '1222','1224','1223' are the X variable names.
What should I do to get the X values back? Thanks!

input

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Data\input.xlsx',sheetname='InputData')
df.head()
df1 = df.ix[:, ['1222','1224','1223','Y']]
df1.head()
```

output

```
1222 1224 1223 Y
NaN  NaN  NaN  0.6785
NaN  NaN  NaN  0.6801
```

Comment: those columns either don't exist or are labeled with integers instead of strings

Comment: .ix is deprecated, use .loc or .iloc.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46915810/6361531

Comment: Thank you both! I changed .ix to .loc, and use [1222, 1224,1223,'Y'], now it works!