# Using .loc or .iloc instead of .ix

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python 3.6.

I have a  `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` and would like to filter the entire DataFrame based on if the column called "Closed Date" is not null. In other words, if it is null in the "Closed Date" column, then remove the whole row from the DataFrame.

My code right now is the following:

```
data = raw_data.ix[raw_data['Closed Date'].notnull()]
```

Though it gets the job done, I get an warming message saying the following:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: DeprecationWarning: 
.ix is deprecated. Please use
.loc for label based indexing or
.iloc for positional indexing
```

I tried this code:

```
data1 = raw_data.loc[raw_data.notnull(), 'Closed Date']
```

But get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

How do I fix this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
data1 = raw_data.loc[raw_data['Closed Date'].notnull()]
```

`.ix` was very similar to the current `.loc` (which is why the correct `.loc` syntax is equivalent to what you were originally doing with `.ix`). The difference, according to [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31593712/6671176) is: "*ix usually tries to behave like loc but falls back to behaving like iloc if a label is not present in the index*"

**Example**:

Taking this dataframe as an example (let's call it `raw_data`):

```
   Closed Date    x
0          1.0  1.0
1          2.0  2.0
2          3.0  NaN
3          NaN  3.0
4          4.0  4.0
```

`raw_data.notnull()` returns this DataFrame:

```
   Closed Date      x
0         True   True
1         True   True
2         True  False
3        False   True
4         True   True
```

You can't index using `.loc` based on a dataframe of boolean values. However, when you do `raw_data['Closed Date'].notnull()`, you end up with a *Series*:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
```

Which *can* be passed to `.loc` as a sort of "boolean filter" to apply onto your dataframe.

**Alternate Solution**

As pointed out by John Clemens, the same can be achieved with `raw_data.dropna(subset=['Closed Date'])`. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for the `.dropna` method outlines how this could be more flexible in some situations (for instance, allowing to drop rows or columns in which any or all values are `NaN` using the `how` argument, etc...)

Comment: You could argue that `raw_data.dropna(subset=['Closed Date'])` is a little more explicit... (and can be extended to do multiple columns and has the `how` option).

Comment: @JonClements I think that is a good point and addresses the XY-ness of the question.  However, I like that this explains what went wrong

Comment: @JonClements True, that would result in the same, and might prove more flexible in some situations; the OP was asking specifically about `.loc` and `.iloc` though

Comment: Indeed - which this does address... not saying it doesn't... Doesn't hurt to realise it's an alternative option that'll work on multiple columns and can operate in place if the OP needed.

Comment: @sacul BTW, don't be shy to include jc's suggestion in your post.  It'll make it more accessible to future readers (with credit of course).

Comment: @piRSquared, good to know, I would have, but I wasn't sure about the etiquette behind that... don't want to step on anyone's toes!

Comment: jc posted the comment to be helpful.  If we wanted an upvote, he would've posted an answer himself.  IMO, I like to incorporate useful comments in my post and I always attribute the edit to the person who helped.  My advice is to attempt to make your post useful and never be shy to give credit to anyone who helped make your post more useful.  Simple don't be a jerk etiquette will work perfectly (-: