# Copy data-frame cell and append to new column on end of data-frame in all rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a data-frame called `'df_main'` in which the # of rows changes with every import of a csv from the user. No matter that amount of rows, the row 'salon totals' and column `'Paid_BB_Percent'` will always exist. I would like to copy the data from `df_main.loc['salon totals', 'Paid_BB_Percent]` and make a new column on the end of the data-frame called `'Store_BB_Percent'` where every cell in the column contains a copy of this data.

The idea is that I am going to have another data-frame which will contain a row `df_manager = df_main[df_main['Employee'].str.contains(manager_name)]` that will be used to find a specific manager row by user input, then a new column will be added like this: `df_manager['Manager_BB_Bonus'] = (df_manager['Service_Sales'] - df_manager['Service_Breakpoint']) * (df_manager['Store_BB_Percent']).round(2)`

Another, and better way to do this, would be to just multiply `df_main.iloc['salon totals', 'Paid_BB_Percent']` by `df_manager['Manager_Service_Diff']` like this:

`df_manager['Manager_BB_Bonus'] = (df_main.loc['salon totals', 'Paid_BB_Percent'] * df_manager['Manager_Service_Diff'])`

The issue with this is when I run:

`df_manager = df_main[df_main['Employee'].str.contains(manager_name)]
df_manager['Service_Breakpoint'] = 1700
df_manager['Manager_Service_Diff'] = (df_manager['Service_Sales'] - df_manager['Service_Breakpoint'])
df_manager['Manager_BB_Bonus'] = (df_main.loc['salon totals', 'Paid_BB_Percent'] * df_manager['Manager_Service_Diff'])
df_manager`

I get the error: "KeyError: 'the label [salon totals] is not in the [index]'"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to multiply a dataframe to a series. What is expected multiplication operation?

Comment: I don't see what you are saying.. This doesn't work either... `df_manager['Manager_BB_Bonus'] = (df_main.loc['salon totals', 'Paid_BB_Percent'] * df_manager.loc['salon totals', 'Manager_Service_Diff'])`

Comment: What does not work? I have posted an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation-how-are-they-different

Comment: Ok. So I was able to do it by using integer location... `df_manager['Manager_BB_Bonus'] = (df_main.iloc[-1, 5] * df_manager['Manager_Service_Diff'])` for anyone who needs this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to multiply three series. Assuming you are trying to multiply the first value

```
 df_main['salon totals'][0]* df_main['Paid_BB_Percent'][0]* df_main['Manager_Service_Diff'][0]
```

Comment: I am trying to multiple a single cell from row 'salon totals' and column 'Paid_BB_Percent' with `df_main['Manager_Service_Diff']`