# Pandas Dataframe .loc Boolean Attaching Index to First Column

Tags: python, pandas

Why does the index seem to get appended to the first column of a .loc boolean selected row of a dataframe?

Dataframe:

```
       date  price
0  20180926    100
1  20180925     99
2  20180924     98
3  20180923     97
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'date': ['20180926', '20180925','20180924','20180923'], 'price': [100,99,98,97]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
a = df.loc[df['date'] == '20180924']
print(a['date'])
```

Yields:

```
2    20180924
Name: date, dtype: object
```

The "2" index seems to be automatically appended to the front of the 'date' field.

Whereas:

```
b=a.iloc[0]['date']
print(b)
```

Yields:

```
20180924
```

I expected both methods to yield the same result as 'b'.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Pandas version is 0.23.1

Comment: You should avoid chained indexing like you have demonstrated

Answer (score 2):

It looks like when you pass a list into loc or iloc on a dataframe, a dataframe will always be returned (notice that `df['date'] == '20180924'` is a list of booleans).

```
type(df.loc[df['date'] == '20180924']) = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(df.loc[[0]]) = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(df.iloc[[0]]) = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

However, if you pass in an index (assuming your dataframe is not multiindexed) into loc or iloc on a dataframe, it will result in a Series:

```
type(df.loc[0]) = pandas.core.series.Series
type(df.iloc[0]) = pandas.core.series.Series
```

`df.loc[0]` and `df.iloc[0]` are identical (though this is not always the case, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation-how-are-they-different) why). This is the result:

```
date     20180926
price         100
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Likewise, if you pass in an index into iloc on a Series, it will result in a scalar (i.e. a value is returned):

```
type(df.iloc[0].iloc[0])
```

In this case you are picking the 0th positioned element in the series `df.iloc[0]`, which is `'20180926'`. Notice that calling `df.iloc[0].loc[0]` is not valid as 0 is NOT an index in this series. The indexes in `df.iloc[0]` series are date and price.

Answer (score 1):

Using `[]` will return the `pd.Series`

```
a['date'][2]
Out[257]: '20180924'
a.iloc[0]['date']
Out[258]: '20180924'

a.loc[2,'date']
Out[259]: '20180924'
```

Comment: how come a['date'][0]  and a['date'][1] throw KeyErrors?  what is in those locations?

Comment: @tommylicious  a['date'][0] here is the explanation , date you select the columns , and [2] is to select the index, since in your a , if you print it , only have the index 2

Comment: `a['date'][0]` and `a['date'][1]` throw KeyErrors since `a` is a dataframe with only one index: 2. It kept that index from the original dataframe, df. Now `a['date']` makes a series (it converts the column 'date' into a series, and keeps the original index). Thus the series will have only one index: 2.

Comment: @Wen no problem :D