# Using Cell Value from 2 different dataframes to do calculations (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have these 2 dataframes

dffouten:

```
                     index          opmerking
DateTime                                     
2018-11-01 08:05:41     20         photocells
2018-11-01 11:40:55     42  trap/roodnoodstop
2018-11-02 07:24:02     62  trap/roodnoodstop
```

and

dffm:

```
                      Counter
traploopext             4
```

What i want to do is divide the amount of times `trap/noodstop` by the traploopext and countervalue of 4
so what I did is:

```
dffouten = dffouten.groupby('opmerking').count()
```

which gives me

```
                   index
opmerking               
photocells             1
trap/roodnoodstop      2
```

and then

```
percentage = (dffm.loc['rectloopext'] / dffouten.loc['trap/roodnoodstop']) * 100
```

but this doesnt work, the strange thing to me is that if use :

```
percentage = (dffm.loc['rectloopext'] / 2) * 100
```

that it gives me the answer.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see your question, but it's solved now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems is necessary specify `column` in function `loc` for return `scalar`, for count values per column is used [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) so for scalar is used `loc` and finally get division between 2 scalars:

```
dffouten = dffouten['opmerking'].value_counts()
print (dffouten)
trap/roodnoodstop    2
photocells           1
Name: opmerking, dtype: int64

#for Series select by index
print (dffouten.loc['trap/roodnoodstop'])
2

#for DataFrame select by index and column
print (dffm.loc['traploopext', 'Counter'])
4

percentage = (dffm.loc['traploopext', 'Counter'] / dffouten.loc['trap/roodnoodstop']) * 100
print (percentage)
200.0
```

More information is possible find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46915810)