# pandas.Series method that returns updated series

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a Series method that acts like update but returns the updated series instead of updating in place?

Put another way, is there a better way to do this:

```
# Original series
ser1 = Series([10, 9, 8, 7], index=[1,2,3,4])

# I want to change ser1 to be [10, 1, 2, 7]
adj_ser = Series([1, 2], index=[2,3])

adjusted = my_method(ser1, adj_ser)

# Is there a builtin that does this already?
def my_method(current_series, adjustments):
    x = current_series.copy()
    x.update(adjustments)
    return(x)
```

Comment: I think the most easy is to use `x.iloc[1:3] = [1,2]`

Comment: nope, op doesn't want to modify the original series, but instead have a new Series with updated values. I'm afraid you will need to to the copy and the update

Comment: Yes that's why I specified `x`, so in the copied series. What's wrong with doing `x = ser1.copy()` and update `x` using `iloc`?

Comment: I should add that in the use case, I have two series already and want to return a third series containing the original updated with the new (this makes update a better choice than loc imho).  Also this example happends to have a numerical index (so x.iloc is appropriate).  In practice, the index is actually a datetime index.

Comment: Well in that case you can use `loc`, but its the same

Comment: As per above.  I have two series already, so to using loc looks like `x.loc[adjustments.index] = adjustments` which is not as nice as `x.update(adjustments)` unless it comes with some performance benefit etc.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution should be [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html), but it update `adj_ser` by `ser1`, also it cast integers to `float`s:

```
adjusted = adj_ser.combine_first(ser1)
print (adjusted)
1    10.0
2     1.0
3     2.0
4     7.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

@nixon is right that `iloc` and `loc` are good for this kind of thing

```
import pandas as pd
# Original series
ser1 = pd.Series([10, 9, 8, 7], index=[1,2,3,4])
ser2 = ser1.copy()
ser3 = ser1.copy()

# I want to change ser1 to be [10, 1, 2, 7]

# One way
ser2.iloc[1:3] = [1,2]
ser2 # [10, 1, 2, 7]


# Another way
ser3.loc[2, 3] = [1,2]
ser3 # [10, 1, 2, 7]
```

Why two different methods?

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-pandas-iloc-ix-and-loc-different-and-related) explains quite well, the major difference between `loc` and `iloc` is labels vs position. My personal shorthand is if you're trying to make adjustments based on the zero-index position of a value use `iloc` otherwise `loc`. YMMV

Comment: This makes an in-place change to ser1 which OP did not want. This is clearly stated in his question

Answer (score 0):

No built-in function other than [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html), but you can use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with a Boolean series:

```
def my_method(current_series, adjustments):
    bools = current_series.index.isin(adjustments.index)
    return current_series.mask(bools, adjustments)
```

However, as the masking process introduces intermediary `NaN` values, your series will be upcasted to `float`. So your `update` solution is best.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
adjusted = ser1.mask(ser1.index.isin(adj_ser.index), adj_ser)
adjusted
```

Output:

```
1    10
2     1
3     2
4     7
dtype: int64
```