# Pandas .ix Example from Pandas for Data Analysis, rewritten

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm a newbie trying to go through Python for Data Analysis.  I've been able to follow along and think Pandas is fantastic.

However, the example on page 127 uses the deprecated `.ix` method and I've tried to rework it a couple of times and am stumped.

Primarily I referenced the thorough explanation here:
[How are Pandas iloc, ix and loc different and related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-pandas-iloc-ix-and-loc-different-and-related/46915810#46915810)

Specifically the section titled 'Simultaneous selection with labels and integer location'

Here's the example in the book:

```
data = DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4)),
 index=['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'Utah', 'New York'],
columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])

[In]: data.ix[['Colorado', 'Utah'], [3, 0, 1]]
[Out]:
four one two
Colorado 7 0 5
Utah 11 8 9
```

And here's my example, based of the SO article, that I can't get to work:

```
labels = ['Colorado','Utah']
ind_names = data.index.get_loc()
index_ints = [df.index.get_loc(label) for label in labels]
print(data.iloc[index_ints,[3,0,1]])
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change `df` to `data` in list comprehension:

```
labels = ['Colorado','Utah']

index_ints = [data.index.get_loc(label) for label in labels]
print(data.iloc[index_ints,[3,0,1]])
          four  one  two
Colorado     7    4    5
Utah        11    8    9
```

Or use [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) for positions by `index` names:

```
print(data.iloc[data.index.get_indexer(labels),[3,0,1]])
#alternatives
#print(data.iloc[data.index.searchsorted(labels),[3,0,1]])
          four  one  two
Colorado     7    4    5
Utah        11    8    9
```

**Detail**:

```
print(data.index.get_indexer(labels))
[1 2]
```

Comment: curious because you're always so helpful - why use list comprehension instead of the simple .loc[]? Generally curious as I do this operation quite a bit, but wondering if there are reasons to do it like you showed above? Thanks!

Comment: @keg5038 - answer is easy - first solution show how is necessary modify code of OP for working, but sure, better is second solution with no list comprehension. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use label-based indexing via [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
data.loc[['Colorado', 'Utah'], data.columns[[3, 0, 1]]]
```