# Python Pandas: Does 'loc' and 'iloc' stand for anything?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been using pandas for a while now, I understand what **`loc`** and **`iloc`** do. 
But till this day I don't know if these **two things stand for** something? Are they short for something or abbreviations? Or are they just random?

I interpret `iloc` as 'index-based-location' which makes sense, but `loc` is a bit problematic to me, I interpret it as 'location' but it doesn't shout 'label-based-location', why couldn't they call it `lloc`?

Comment: It's Label based locating, and Integer based locating see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation-how-are-they-different) it's been asked before. I'd say pronounce it **Label of Column** and **Index/Integer of Column**

Comment: Two separate things, I want to understand the meaning behind the words, not the functionality of it.

Comment: Would [this](http://jose-coto.com/slicing-methods-pandas) help? In particular the last section where it says: *"So, this is what you need to remember:"*

Comment: Also see [this](https://github.com/datacarpentry/python-ecology-lesson/issues/7) issue on github, It seems it isn't really a standard abbreviation persay but more "location" as lamens location, `loc`, and "integer location" as the way a computer sees it. `iloc`

Comment: You're not getting it, I understand what they do, but I wanted to know if they stand for something? Loc does't really translate to LABEL based indexing does it? So I wanted to understand what they've named it Loc and iLoc

Comment: Ah see now you are answering the question. Loc = Location, and iLoc = Integer Location. Which is what I normally think of but Location could be index or label to me. Which is why I wanted to understand if there's more to it.

Comment: I guess loc is location and iloc is integer location. The assumption being that location stands for what the actual indexes are. It used to trip me up because index and integer both start with "i".... I wonder if there is anything else to the nomenclature too.

Comment: I knew as you said *"I've been using pandas for a while now, I understand what loc and iloc do"* Just doesn't seem like there is a real correlating abreviation symantically. It really is just *lamens* location vs integer location. Human readable labels vs computer logical indexing. Happens for everyone where you know what something does but it's unsettling when you try to rationalize it's meaning or how it does it. Seems that's a Pythonista's nightmare and dream all in one

Comment: This isn't the 80's. public api, without question, should not be shortened or be an acronym. Imagine, reducing all the time spent trying to figure out what this function and its ilk stand for. we'd probably be 50% bionic by now

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### TLDR

It seems there is no abbreviation semantically or in the docs; other than it really is just in lamens: "location" vs "integer location". Or **Human-Readable Labels** vs **Computer-Logical Indexing**.

It happens for everyone, especially with new or complicated languages or ideologies; where you know what something does and how to use it, but it's unsettling when you try to rationalize it's meaning or sort of explain or talk yourself through it.

Seems that's a programmer's nightmare and dream all in one.

---

How I see it, put yourself in a situation where you work at a department store and someone asks you where to find the soda, you can either tell them it's in the "soda" aisle or it's on isle 19. *(or: `aisles["soda"]` vs `aisles[19]`)* both point to the same location.

---

To properly answer your question, as you are asking *"Does `loc` and `iloc` stand for anything?"* and **not** *What is the difference between `loc` and `iloc`?*.

I've done some research on this as well, and found from [this github issue](https://github.com/datacarpentry/python-ecology-lesson/issues/7)
which lead me to [this summary](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.0/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing). And from these docs, I believe this sums up with these statements

**[Different Choices for Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.0/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing)**

> Object selection has had a number of user-requested additions in order
> to support more explicit location based indexing.

> - **`.loc`**: is primarily **label** based
> - **`.iloc`**: is primarily **integer** position based

> *And on the chance we want to include `ix`*

> - `.ix` supports mixed integer and label based access. It is primarily label based, but will fall back to integer positional access [continue](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html)

**Selection By Label**

> pandas provides a suite of methods in order to have purely **label** based indexing... - [continued](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.0/indexing.html#selection-by-label)

> - The **`.loc`** attribute is the primary access method. ↑

**Selection By Position**

> pandas provides a suite of methods in order to get purely **integer** based indexing...
>
> - [continued](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.0/indexing.html#selection-by-position)

> - The **`.iloc`** attribute is the primary access method. ↑

This does also apply to `.at` and `.iat` as well.

> Similarly to `loc`, **`at`** provides **label** based scalar lookups, while, **`iat`** provides **integer** based lookups analogously to `iloc`

<sub>*By the way I retracted my close vote and gave you an upvote as that did take some guts to ask for more clarification on an already over asked topic but I do know I as well had issues with that when I was learning too.* Hope this helps</sub>

Comment: Only the last part (under "To sum up") is relevant, the rest talks about what loc/iloc do again. You might want to consider removing those parts to make your answer clearer.

Comment: I edited it a bit for readability; I know I could have answered with just my comment but I wanted to include as much context as I felt necessary for newcomers unless it really isn’t helpful.

Comment: I like this. "location" vs "integer location". Human Readable Labels vs Computer Logical Indexing.

Answer (score 0):

'loc' is meant to use 'explicit index' supplied during series/dataframe creation, while 'iloc' will lead us to 'implicit Python index' to select data.

```
In [1]: data = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], index=[1, 3, 5]) 
        data 
Out[1]: 1   a   
        3   b 
        5   c 
        dtype: object 

In [2]: # explicit index when indexing
       data[1]
Out[2]: 'a'

In [3]: # implicit index when slicing
        data[1:3]
Out[3]: 3 b
        5 c
        dtype: object
```

As it is said, explicit index is always better than implicit one.