# How to drop a series of rows from dataframe in a faster way

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data set and I want to drop some rows with a faster method. I had tried the following code but it took a long time

I want to drop every user who makes less than 3 operations.

every operation is stored in a row in which user_id is not the ID of my data

```
undesirable_users=[] 
for i in range(len(operations_per_user)):
    if operations_per_user.get_value(operations_per_user.index[i])<=3:
        undesirable_users.append(operations_per_user.index[i])

for i in range(len(undesirable_users)):
    data = data.drop(data[data.user_id == undesirable_users[i]].index)
```

`data` is a dataframe and `operation_per_user` is a series created by: `operation_per_user = data['user_id'].value_counts()`.

Comment: Can you show what `operations_per_user` and `data` look like? Might make it easier to suggest a solution

Comment: concerning my data it is a dataframe and operation per user is a series that is created by : operation_per_user = data['user_id'].value_counts()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just filter them? You don't need to loop at all.

You can get the filtered indexes by:

```
operations_per_user.index[operations_per_user <= 3]
```

And then you can filter these indexes from the df, making the solution:

```
data = data[data['user_id'] not in (operations_per_user.index[operations_per_user <= 3])]
```

**EDIT**

My understanding is that you want to remove any user that occurs less than 3 times in the data. You won't need to create a `value_counts` list for that, you could do a `groupby` and find the counts and then filter on that basis.

```
filtered_user_ids = data.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 3)['user_id'].tolist()

data = data[~data[user_id].isin(filtered_user_ids)]
```

Comment: thanks! but I get this erreor : TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: thanks a lot but  I get the following error during executng the second instruction( data=data[.....]) : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: That was a quick fix. Have a look

Comment: Thank you razdi I do appreciate your help It works now

Answer (score 0):

- If `data` is a pandas `DataFrame`, and it contains both `user_id` and `operations_per_user` as columns, you should perform the drop with:

```
data = data.drop(data.loc[data['operations_per_user'] <= 3].index)
```

**Edit**

Instead of creating a seperate series, you could add `operations_per_user` to `data` with:

```
data['operations_per_user'] = data.loc[:, 'user_id'].value_counts()
```

You could either perform the drop as above or perform the selection with the inverse logical condition:

```
data = data.loc[data['operations_per_user' > 3]]
```

**Original**

It would be preferable if you could supply some more information about the variables used in your code.

- If `operations_per_user` is a pandas `Series`, your first loop could be improved with:

```
undesirable_users=[] 
for i in operations_per_user.index:
    if operations_per_user.loc[i] <= 3:
        undesirable_users.append(i)
```

The function `get_value()` is deprecated, use `loc` or `iloc` instead. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-ix-and-loc-different) is a good summary of `loc` and `iloc`, and [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) is a great pandas cheatsheet to reference.

- You can use python lists as iterators; for your second loop:

```
for user in undesirable_users:
    data = data.drop(data.loc[data['user_id'] == user].index)
```

Comment: thanks! concerning the usage of get_value() it works with me usually very faster than iloc and loc. moreover, I had used your code but it s executed slowly. I need a faster method. thank you again

Comment: concerning my data it is a dataframe and operation per user is a series that is created by : operation_per_user = data['user_id'].value_counts()

Comment: @Nirmine - See the edit, you can just add the values from the `operation_per_user` series to `data` as a column, then perform the drop/logical selection in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than dropping, you can simply select the rows you want to keep reverting the logical condition.

First, select the user to keep only.
Then get a boolean list, length equal to `data` rows.
Finally, select the rows to keep.

```
keepusers = operation_per_user.loc[operation_per_user > 3]
tokeep = [uid in keepuser for uid in data['user_id']]
newdata = data.loc[tokeep]
```