# python KeyError: even when the column name exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, keyerror

I am attempting to index a pandas dataframe by a column in the dataframe and get KeyError.  For example,
the dataframe has rows indexed on general ledger account name ('Cash','Securities', etc) and the columns are indexed by the time period ('Q1_2018', 'Q2_2018', etc.).  These values are confirmed when I use df.index and df.columns.  However, when i run df.loc['Cash','Q1_2018'], it returns the following KeyError: 'Q1_2018'.  Any thoughts on why this would occur.

```
            Q1_2018     Q2_2018     Q3_2018
Cash        2000000     2000100     1900000
Securites   3000000     2999900     2910000
```

Comment: `iloc` takes integers as input. use `df.loc['Cash', 'Q1_2018']`.

Comment: Maybe you have Q1_2018 with some spaces around it in the column.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  This is not the issue as I have double-checked.  I get the error message no matter which quarter I try to index, and they are all spelled correctly with no known extra spaces.

Comment: @carrie3zz Please, show the code that creates the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have used iloc with labels of your dataframe. Do note that since you are using labels, you should be trying with loc instead.

Here are some pages that might interest you on how both methods work:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

loc vs iloc
[How are iloc, ix and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-ix-and-loc-different)

Comment: I mistyped in the original post.  I am using loc not iloc.

Comment: In that case, may i suggest you edit your post so as not to confuse others?

Comment: I tried to edit initially and could not figure out how.  Now it is updated.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this? Currently pulling my hair out at the same issue