# I need to print a string on the first multi-index in a date format

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I need to print a string on the first multi-index in a date format.

[image]

[image]

Essentially, I need to delete all data on the first date. But finding out the cause of this error is also very important to me. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: `date_our_full.loc['2019-09-13']`, not `iloc`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are iloc, ix and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-ix-and-loc-different)

Comment: @QuangHoang KeyError: '2019-09-13'

Comment: Also, I believe `dt.date` does not give you back pandas datetime series, so you can't slice by string.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney
I will take this into account in the future.

Comment: @QuangHoang 
Could you also tell me how I can derive averages from the Time Index?

Answer (score 0):

As commented `dt.date` returns `datetime.date` object, which is different from Pandas' `datetime` object. Use `dt.floor('D')` or `dt.normalized()` instead. For example, this would work:

```
df['Date'] = df.session_started.dt.normalize()
df['Time'] = df.session_started.dt.hour

df_hour = df.groupby(['Date','Time']).checkbooking.count()
df_hour.loc['2019-01-13']
```