# How to keep only a certain set of rows by index in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, astronomy

I have a DataFrame I created by doing the following manipulations to a .fits file:

```
data_dict= dict()
for obj in sortedpab:
    for key in ['FIELD', 'ID',  'RA' , 'DEC' , 'Z_50', 'Z_84','Z_16' , 'PAB_FLUX', 'PAB_FLUX_ERR']:
        data_dict.setdefault(key, list()).append(obj[key])

gooddf = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
gooddf['Z_ERR']= ((gooddf['Z_84'] - gooddf['Z_50']) + (gooddf['Z_50'] - gooddf['Z_16'])) / (2 * 
gooddf['Z_50'])
gooddf['OBS_PAB'] = 12820 * (1 + gooddf['Z_50'])
gooddf.loc[gooddf['FIELD'] == "ERS" , 'FIELD'] = "ERSPRIME"
gooddf = gooddf[['FIELD' , 'ID' , 'RA' , 'DEC' , 'Z_50' , 'Z_ERR' , 'PAB_FLUX' , 'PAB_FLUX_ERR' , 
'OBS_PAB']]
gooddf = gooddf[gooddf.OBS_PAB <= 16500]
```

Which gives me a DataFrame with 351 rows and 9 columns. I would like to keep rows only according to certain indices, and I thought for example doing something of this sort:

```
indices = [5 , 6 , 9 , 10]
gooddf = gooddf[gooddf.index == indices]
```

where I would like it to keep only the rows with the index values listed in the array indices, but this is giving me issues.

I found a way to do this with a for loop:

```
good = np.array([5 , 6 , 9 , 12 , 14 , 15 , 18 , 21 , 24 , 29 , 30 , 35 , 36 , 37 , 46 , 48 ])

gooddf50 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(good)):
    gooddf50 = gooddf50.append(gooddf[gooddf.index == good[i]])
```

Any thoughts on how to do this in a better way, preferably using just pandas?

Comment: `gooddf.iloc[indices]`?

Comment: @ALollz I am not sure what this is doing, but it returns indices 10, 11, 15 when I use     `good = np.array([5 , 6 , 9])` and then
`gooddf.iloc[good]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```py
gooddf.loc[indices]
```

An important note: `.iloc` and `.loc` are doing slightly different things, which is why you may be getting unexpected results.

You can read deeper into the details of indexing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31593712/6513736), but the key thing to understand is that `.iloc` returns rows according to the **positions** specified, whereas `.loc` returns rows according to the **index labels** specified. So if your indices aren't sorted, `.loc` and `.iloc` will behave differently.