# How to keep only a certain set of rows by index in a pandas DataFrame with rule

Tags: python, dataframe

Following up on this answer [How to keep only a certain set of rows by index in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493771/how-to-keep-only-a-certain-set-of-rows-by-index-in-a-pandas-dataframe) I need to extend it a bit:

E. g. I only want to keep rows where it's index follows a rule. In my case '01' through '99'. do I have to write a series from 01 to 99 to filter the rows?
Or would be some kind of regex OK? `gooddf.loc['[0-9]']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, making sure that you specify the start with "^" and end of the match with "$" will be appropriate.

```
import pandas as pd

gooddf = pd.DataFrame({"K":[2,3,4,6,2]}, index=["01", "101", "98", "201", "032"])

match_in = gooddf.index.str.match("^[0-9]{1,2}$")
gooddf[match_in]
```