# The difference between df.loc and df.iloc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)  
df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))
display(df_new)

diff_BC= []
for i in range(len(df_new)):
    diff_BC.append(df_new.loc[i]['B'] - df_new.loc[i]['C'])
df_new['difference'] = diff_BC
display(df_new['difference'])
print(type(i))
```

I don't understand why `df_new.loc[i]['B'] - df_new.loc[i]['C']` works, I think it should give an error , because `type(i)` is `int` and should use `iloc`.

Comment: Because unless specified otherwise, a dataframe will have a `RangeIndex` which assigns keys from 0..len(df)... so the index for the row is the same as the location for the row... `print(df.index)` for instance...

Comment: `.loc` finds the *name* of the index. And if your index is numbers, as it is, it will find them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are iloc, ix and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-ix-and-loc-different)