# How to change/access specific values in Dataframe from pandas in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe object from pandas and I wanted to know if there is any way that I can access a specific value from a specific column and change it.

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df

gameboard = df([['#','#',"#"],['#','#',"#"],['#','#',"#"]], columns = [1, 2, 3], index = [1,2,3])
print(gameboard)
```

Like for example, I wanted to change the '#'  from the second  'second'  list.
Or if gameboard was a 2d list how can I access gameboard[1][1]'s element.

Comment: Take a look at, [How are iloc ix and loc differrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-ix-and-loc-different)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the .iloc function
(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

to access said value you would need to call something like:

```
gameboard.iloc[1, 1] = 6
```

iloc would essentially call the second row (that's what the `[1` is) and then you choose the location of the value in the list (`, 1]` for the second value in our case). Finally you assign whatever new value you want that to be.

Your output would be:

```
    1   2   3
1   #   #   #
2   #   6   #
3   #   #   #
```

edit using alollz recommendation.