# Python dataframe - access data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe like this -
[image: dataframe pic]

To access elements in the first column, is this the best pythonic way -

```
df['time_6'].iloc[0][0]
```

?

If I am going to use a For loop to parse through this column, would the best way be to use
`.iloc[ii][ii]`  ?

Thank you

R

Comment: And [How are iloc and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different)

Comment: I figure I can use df['time_6'].values instead  which generates an array that I can parse through