# How to remove a row that has no index number - Python

Tags: python, pandas, row

I am a newbie in Python.

Say I have the following very simple table saved in a text file:

```
one two three
four five six
seven eight nine
```

I can view this table using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('table.txt')
print(df)
```

The outcome of this is:

```
      one two three
0     four five six
1  seven eight nine
```

Now, I want to delete the first row (i.e. `one two three`). My first thought was to write:

```
df.drop([0])
```

Because rows and columns are numbered starting from 0. But what this does is that it drops the second row (i.e. `four five six`).

Thus the title of this question. How to remove a row that has no index number? Because as seen from `print(df)`, the first row is not given an index.

I did try to Google this, but I was not able to find an answer. This is probably because I do not know some keywords.

Comment: The first row is interpreted as a header. Use `read_csv("table.txt", header=None)` and drop the first row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are iloc and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One Two Three** is the header of CSV file.
So to skip it, write the code mentioned below:

**df = pd.read_csv('table.txt', header=none)**