# Does iloc use the indices or the place of the row

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have extracted few rows from a dataframe to a new dataframe. In this new dataframe old indices remain. However, when i want to specify range from this new dataframe i used it like new indices, starting from zero. Why did it work? Whenever I try to use the old indices it gives an error.

`germany_cases = virus_df_2[virus_df_2['location'] == 'Germany']`

`germany_cases = germany_cases.iloc[:190]`

This is the code. The rows that I extracted from the dataframe virus_df_2 have indices between 16100 and 16590. I wanted to take the first 190 rows. in the second line of code i used iloc[:190] and it worked. However, when i tried to use iloc[16100:16290] it gave an error. What could be the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are iloc and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different)

Answer (score 0):

In pandas there are two attributes, `loc` and `iloc`.

The `iloc` is, as you have noticed, an indexing based on the order of the rows in memory, so there you can reference the nth line using `iloc[n]`.

In order to reference rows using the pandas indexing, which can be manually altered  and can not only be integers but also strings or other objects that are hashable (have the `__hash__` method defined), you should use `loc` attribute.

In your case, `iloc` raises an error because you are trying to access a range that is outside the region defined by your dataframe. You can try `loc` instead and it will be ok.

At first it will be hard to grasp the indexing notation, but it can be very helpful in some circumstances, like for example sorting or performing grouping operations.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example that might help:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        France=[1, 2, 3],
        Germany=[4, 5, 6],
        UK=['x', 'y', 'z'],
    ))
df = df.loc[:,"Germany"].iloc[1:2]
```

Out:

```
1    5
Name: Germany, dtype: int64
```

Hope I could help.