# Python DataFrame with two instances under same index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new to Python.
I've been working in a project, and have a DataFrame that gives me two different instances for the same index. I exlpain:
When I ask for an instance this way:

```
df[df.name == 'Marcia']
```

the result shows `Int64Index([92], dtype='int64')`

But if I ask for an instance by index `= 92` this way:

```
df.iloc[92]
```

the result is a different instance, whose 'name' is not 'Marcia'.
There is only one 'Marcia' in my dataset.
How can this happen?

Comment: df[df.name == 'Marcia'] should give a dataframe, if it passes, with name column. What is Int64Index([92], dtype='int64') then?

Comment: It gave a dataframe (the original but filtered for name = 'Marcia'), but then came the message indicating that the index of that observation was 92, as stated in the first index column.

Comment: perhaps you could show entire output, `Int64Index([92], dtype='int64')` still a bit unclear

Answer (score 1):

`df.iloc[92]` takes the `92th` row in your dataframe. As your dataframe is shuffled, or some rows have been deleted during data wrangling steps, the row with index-name `92` may not be the `92th` row anymore.

Try using `df.loc[92]` instead, as it returns the row with index-name `92`.

See [How are iloc and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different) for more information.