# Finding entries in a DataFrame that fall above a threshold

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In a dataframe as such named pd:

| country | 1980 | 1990 | 2000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| India. | 800 | 2000 | 3500 |
| China | 200 | 2000 | 1500 |
| UK. | 160 | 150 | 400 |

How can we find the rows where the values of year 2000 are greater than 1000?

I see there are two ways:

```
pd.loc[pd['2000'] > 1000]
```

and

```
pd[pd['2000'] > 1000]
```

is there a difference in the two methods? I see it produces the same results but don't understand if there is a difference.

Thanks

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different

Answer (score 0):

The first case is generally better because the second (indexing the dataframe instead of using `df.loc`) sometimes returns a copy of data and sometimes returns a view depending on how it's used. The difference is explained here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=assigning%20view#indexing-view-versus-copy

I don't think it matters unless you're assigning to the selection, but as a rule of thumb it's best to use a series of selection criteria in `df.loc[]`, for example `pd.loc[(pd['2000'] > 1000), 'columnName']`

Comment: this is wonderful! That makes sense. It's more of a use by case in a way!