# Why can't I use loc to access an element on a dataframe after using apply?

Tags: python, dataframe, apply, series

I'd like to group a dataset by an ID column that I set up.
So I have:
df_grouped = df_grouped.groupby(by='groupID').apply(create_ohlc)

and create_ohlc is the following:

```
def create_ohlc(data):
    data['open'] = data.loc[0, 'price']
    data['high'] =data.loc[:, 'price'].max()
    data['low'] = data.loc[:, 'price'].min()
    data['close'] = data.loc[-1, 'price']
    return data
```

I could fix it by doing like that:
def create_ohlc(data):
data['open'] = data.loc[data.index[0], 'price']
data['high'] =data.loc[:, 'price'].max()
data['low'] = data.loc[:, 'price'].min()
data['close'] = data.loc[data.index[-1], 'price']
return data

But I still don't understand what is going on.
And it takes a bit of time to get it done. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a combination of integer indexing and label indexing, it's better to go with the integer indexing and get the index of your labels [read docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)

```
data['open'] = data.iloc[0, data.columns.get_loc('price')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `loc` gets rows by labels.
On the other hand, `iloc` gets rows by index.

See also [How are iloc and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different)