# Random access with loc[] in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In the following code, I expect that in each iteration of the loop, `batch_df` index starts from 0, however, as you can see, in the second iteration the index starts from 3.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.batch.csv')
print(df)
for i in range(0, len(df), 3):
    print("\n------BATCH BEGIN")
    batch_df = df.iloc[i:i+3]
    print(batch_df)
    print(batch_df.loc[0].at["Name"])
    print("------BATCH END")
```

Output

```
   ID Name Metric  Value
0   0   K1     M1     10
1   0   K1     M2      5
2   0   K1     M3     10
3   1   K2     M1     20
4   1   K2     M2     10
5   1   K2     M3     15

------BATCH BEGIN
   ID Name Metric  Value
0   0   K1     M1     10
1   0   K1     M2      5
2   0   K1     M3     10
K1
------BATCH END

------BATCH BEGIN
   ID Name Metric  Value
3   1   K2     M1     20
4   1   K2     M2     10
5   1   K2     M3     15
ERROR ----> 7     print(batch_df.loc[0].at["Name"])
KeyError: 0
```

I can fix the code with this modification `print(batch_df.loc[i].at["Name"])`, but I want to know why that happens and does that mean the first batch_df is not overwritten?

Comment: `df.iloc` does references by row num,ber.  `df.loc` does references by your index column.  When you take a subset, the index column remains intact, as you can see -- the first row has index 3.

Comment: Use `.iloc[0]` or `head(1)` to get the first row.

Comment: Related [How are iloc and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31593201/15497888)