# Change values in DataFrame - .iloc vs .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hey I write this code:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {"KEY": ["KEY1", "KEY2", "KEY3"], "value": ["A", "B", "C"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df1["value 2"] = "nothing"

d2 = {"KEY": ["KEY2"], "value_alternative": ["D"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

for k in range(3):
    key = df1.iloc[k]["KEY"]
    print(key)
    if key in list(df2["KEY"]):
        df1.iloc[k]["value 2"] = df2.loc[df2["KEY"] == key, "value_alternative"].item()
    else: 
        df1.iloc[k]["value 2"] = df1.iloc[k]["value"]
```

but unfortunately values in `df1["value 2"]` haven't changed :( I rewrite it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {"KEY": ["KEY1", "KEY2", "KEY3"], "value": ["A", "B", "C"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df1["value 2"] = "nothing"

d2 = {"KEY": ["KEY2"], "value_alternative": ["D"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

for k in range(3):
    key = df1.iloc[k]["KEY"]
    print(key)
    if key in list(df2["KEY"]):
        df1.loc[k, "value 2"] = df2.loc[df2["KEY"] == key, "value_alternative"].item()
    else: 
        df1.loc[k, "value 2"] = df1.iloc[k]["value"]
```

and then everything works fine, but I dont understand why the previous method don't work. What is the easiest way to change value in dataframe in a loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are iloc and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different)

Comment: You "intuition" or coding style is probably influenced by other programing languages such as C/C++ where to access an element of an nD array you would do something like `array[x][y]...[n]` (or even python itself). In pandas dataframes that leads to your "problem". If you read the top most of the [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position) suggested by IronWidget you will get an answer to most missing knowledge here. With that, you can re-work your intuition on how to index positions in series and dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. Don't use a for loop with dataframes if you really really have to.
Just use a boolean array to filter your dataframe with `loc` and assign your values that way.
You can do what you want with a simple merge.

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='KEY', how='left').rename(columns={'value_alternative': 'value 2'})
df1.loc[df1['value 2'].isna(), 'value 2'] = df1['value']
```

Reason for `iloc` not working with assignment is in pandas you can't set a value in a copy of a dataframe. Pandas does this in order to work fast. To have access to the underlying data you need to use `loc` for filtering. Don't forget `loc` and `iloc` do different things. `loc` looks at the lables of the index while `iloc` looks at the index number.

In order for this to work you also have to delete the

```
df1["value 2"] = "nothing"
```

line from your program

Answer (score 0):

You've found a VERY subtle behavior of Pandas. There's more here than most people think.

**Short answer**: you can always change a single entry of a `DataFrame` using a **single** use of `loc` as follows:

```py
d1 = {"KEY": ["KEY1", "KEY2", "KEY3"], "value": ["A", "B", "C"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1) # default index: [0, 1, 2]
df1['new_col'] = -1 # SHOCKINGLY RELEVANT, see "The weirdness" below!!

idx = 2 # a value of your DataFrame's index (not to be confused with row number/iloc)
col = 'KEY'
newValue = 'NEW_VALUE'
df1.loc[idx, col] = newValue # always succeeds: entry is modified in place
```

The key word above is **single**: the following alternatives use ["chained indexing"](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) in Pandas terminology. They do not always work, but sometimes do (see "The weirdness" below).

```py
# df1.loc[idx, col] = newValue # for reference; this always works

df1.loc[idx][col] = newValue # sometimes doesn't work, prints a warning

rowNum = 3
df1.iloc[rowNum][col] = newValue # sometimes doesn't work, does't print a warning
```

The reason is that `df.loc[idx]` and `df.iloc[rowNum]` in your example are returning a `Series` that has a *copy* of the row. So the subsequent `[...]`, aka `__setitem__` calls, mutate the copy. Thus they don't update the original `DataFrame`. This is what's happening when the chained indexing versions don't work. But in other situations the chained indexing *does* work. Read on!

**The weirdness:**

The best way to explain the weirdness is to show you an example:

```py
d1 = {"KEY": ["KEY1", "KEY2", "KEY3"], "value": ["A", "B", "C"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

# BEFORE adding a new column
df1.loc[0, 'KEY'] = 'UPDATED_KEY1' # works
df1.loc[1]['KEY'] = 'UPDATED_KEY2' # also works
df1.iloc[2]['KEY'] = 'UPDATED_KEY3' # also also works

df1['new_col'] = -1 # adds a new column with entries [-1, -1, -1]

# AFTER adding a new column
df1.loc[1]['KEY'] = 'APPLE' # does NOT work! Prints a warning.

# but if you make a deep copy, it works again
df2 = df1.copy()
df2.loc[1]['KEY'] = 'APPLE' # WORKS
```

So to summarize:

- using non-chained indexing, i.e. a single `loc`, always works
- if you create a `DataFrame` and immediately use use "chained indexing" (two more more `[...]` back-to-back), then it works. The intermediate `Series` is a modifiable view of the row
- but after adding a new column, as you did in your original code, chained indexing does NOT work. The returned `Series` is a copy.
- but if you copy the `DataFrame`, chained indexing on the copy works

Your original code added a new column before doing any updates. That's why the chained indexing form of the updates didn't work.

I have no explanation for this behavior. My best guess is this exposes an implementation detail in the way adding columns works. Perhaps other `DataFrame` modifications break chained indexing updates as well. If anyone knows, please leave a comment!

*Final obligatory comment:* Pandas has faster, vectorized alternatives to operating on a `DataFrame` with a `for` loop in most situations. But I get it: sometimes you really just need to update one entry, and this is the clearest way to do it.

Comment: Is this ChatGPT generated?

Comment: Definitely not. Either that, or I'm ChatGPT 6 and I've passed the Turing Test.