# Pandas: Get cell value by row index and column name

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have a pandas dataframe:

```
   name  age  sal
0  Alex   20  100
1  Jane   15  200
2  John   25  300
3   Lsd   23  392
4   Mari  21  380
```

Let's say, a few rows are now deleted and we don't know the indexes that have been deleted. For example, we delete row index 1 using `df.drop([1])`. And now the data frame comes down to this:

```
  fname  age  sal
0  Alex   20  100
2  John   25  300
3   Lsd   23  392
4   Mari  21  380
```

I would like to get the value from row index 3 and column "age". It should return 23. How do I do that?

`df.iloc[3, df.columns.get_loc('age')]` does not work because it will return 21. I guess iloc takes the consecutive row index?

Comment: Then it's better to set your index to 'fname': `df = df.set_index('fname')`. If you're going to referencing rows by that. There's not much point in using an arbitrary integer index when you can use something better. (unless there's a possiblity of duplicates in 'fname')

Comment: Shouldn't guess but read the docs and use `loc` here :)

Comment: i think this thread answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different

Comment: Related: "[pandas loc vs. iloc vs. at vs. iat?](/q/28757389/90527)"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `.loc` to get rows by label and `.iloc` to get rows by position:

```
>>> df.loc[3, 'age']
23

>>> df.iloc[2, df.columns.get_loc('age')]
23
```

More about [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: Warning. `pandas.DataFrame.iloc` is deprecated since version 2.2.0

Comment: @AlexisLP. You are right but that is not relevant to the current answer (tested with `Pandas==2.2.0`

Answer (score 2):

Another way apart from the accepted answere is `df.at[3, "age"]`

Answer (score 1):

try this one:
`[label, column name]`

```
value = df.loc[1,"column_name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset = ({'name':['Alex', 'Jane', 'John', 'Lsd', 'Mari'],
       'age': [20, 15, 25, 23, 21],
       'sal': [100, 200, 300, 392, 380]})
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df.drop([1], inplace=True)
df.loc[3,['age']]
```

Comment: please always provide supporting textual information to explain why your answer works.