# Do loc and iloc methods behave differently in assignment?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I need to add a new column to a dataframe based on an ID in the other one.

I created a small snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame([['ass-123-43', ['123', '456']],['ass-123-44', ['123', '457']]], columns=['customer_id', 'order_id']) 
b = pd.DataFrame([['ass-123-43'], ['ass-123-44']], columns=['customer_id'])

dict_a = a.set_index('customer_id').order_id.to_dict()

b['order_id'] = np.nan

for customer_id, order_id in dict_a.items():
    if customer_id in b.customer_id.values:
        b.iloc[b.customer_id == customer_id, 1] = pd.Series([order_id])

print(b)
```

When I use the iloc method, the code works as expected:

```
  customer_id    order_id
0  ass-123-43  [123, 456]
1  ass-123-44  [123, 457]
```

But when I use loc method it doesn't work as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame([['ass-123-43', ['123', '456']],['ass-123-44', ['123', '457']]], columns=['customer_id', 'order_id'])
b = pd.DataFrame([['ass-123-43'], ['ass-123-44']], columns=['customer_id'])

dict_a = a.set_index('customer_id').order_id.to_dict()

b['order_id'] = np.nan

for customer_id, order_id in dict_a.items():
    if customer_id in b.customer_id.values:
        b.loc[b.customer_id == customer_id, 'order_id'] = pd.Series([order_id])

print(b)
```

I got this result:

```
  customer_id    order_id
0  ass-123-43  [123, 456]
1  ass-123-44         NaN
```

Beyond loc using labels to assign the row and iloc a number, is there something else I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more about the differences between `.iloc` and `.loc` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31593201/17242583), but for your particular case, the reason you're getting NaN is because of *what* you're assigning. With `.iloc`, it completely ignores the **index** of the value that you're assigning (which is `pd.Series([order_id])`), so it works fine and doesn't produce NaN.

With `.loc`, however, it *does* respect the index. In your example, `pd.Series([order_id])` has an index of `[0]`, as you can see:

```
>>> order_id = '123'
>>> pd.Series([order_id])
0    123
dtype: object
```

Now look at the index of the row where the NaN is occuring. It's **`1`**. But the index of the value you're trying to assign to it is `0`, as shown above. **Mismatched indexes!** What happens? The missing value - *NaN*.

---

If you *want* use `.loc` instead of `.iloc`, you can avoid this mismatched-index problem by converting the Series object to a numpy array (using `.to_numpy()`) before assigning:

```
b.loc[b.customer_id == customer_id, 'order_id'] = pd.Series([order_id]).to_numpy()
```

That will work as expected.