# Building a sum in a for loop from a dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops

I have a dataset with two columns, Earning and Inflation_rate
Assuming the Dataset looks like this

```
0   Earning   Inflation_rate
1   10000       0.00
2   12000       0.12
3   13000       0.13
```

I need to see how much it has built up over the course of these years, the formula is
(Income build until last year x inflation rate) + (first year earning/75)

For Year 1 that would be:
( 0 x 0.00 ) + (10000/75)

For Year 2 that would be:
(133 x 0.12) + (12000/75)

My code is the following:

```
y=int(input("Please enter the number of years of contribution: "))
income_built=0
divide=75

for i in range(1,y+1):
    income_built=(income_built*df['Inflation_rate'].iloc[i-1,i])+(df['Earning'].iloc[i-1,i])/divide

print(int(income_built))
```

And I get the error
IndexingError: Too many indexers

How can I solve this ? Thank you!

Comment: **Year 2 that would be: (133 x 0.12) + (12000/75)**  where does that `133` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from your use of `df['Inflation_rate'].iloc[i-1,i]` and `df['Earning'].iloc[i-1,i]`.

Pandas has a number of different ways of accessing values in a df, but the two most used are `loc` and `iloc`, both of which are explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different).

I am slightly unclear about the formula you're trying to use. But I think if `df['Inflation_rate'].iloc[i-1,i]` is changed to `df.loc[i-1,'Inflation_rate']` and `df['Earning'].iloc[i-1,i]` is changed to `df.loc[i-1,'Earning'`, the error should dissappear.