# Unable to assign different values in each cell of a column in dataframe, containing 99,000 records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, outliers

I want to change values greater than 70 in column CT_feat7 but it only changes till 59000. After that, I have to run the iteration again, with a different index value.

Please, explain why this happens. Is there a better way?
Dataset [before replacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSyVy.png). After I run this code:

```
for index,j in enumerate(df['CT_feat7']):
  if j>70:
    df.loc[index,'CT_feat7'] = 11+random.random()
```

values are changed only [up to index 59180.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iASld.png)

```
i,j = 59180,2
while i <= 99195:
  if df.loc[i,'CT_feat7']>70:
    df.loc[i,'CT_feat7'] = j
    j+=0.1
    if j>12:
      j=2
  i+=1
```

Comment: It would help if you share some example data where this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because `enumerate()` is not the proper iterator to use with `.loc`. Try:

```
for index,j in df['CT_feat7'].items():
  if j>70:
    df.loc[index,'CT_feat7'] = 11+random.random()
```

`enumerate()` works on the first ~50,000 rows because that is (I suspect) how many rows are in `df`. This is because `enumerate()` iterates over the values `j` in the passed Series and for each `j`, the corresponding `index` is the *location* of `j` in the Series, ranging from 0 to the length of the Series. However, when slicing with `.loc`, you must give the *label* (not the location) of the item(s) you want. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for answering and can you explain as to why enumerate works till 50,000 after which it fails??