# Why doesn't .loc reverse slice correctly?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

From my understanding, there are two ways to subset a dataframe in pandas:

a) `df['columns']['rows']`
b) `df.loc['rows', 'columns']`

I was following a guided case study, where the instruction was to select the first and last n rows of a column in a dataframe. The solution used Method A, whereas I tried Method B.

My method wasn't working and I couldn't for the life of me figure out why.

I've created a [simplified version of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR5Pm.png)...

```
male = [6, 14, 12, 13, 21, 14, 14, 14, 14, 18]
female = [9, 11, 6, 10, 11, 13, 12, 11, 9, 11]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Male': male,
                    'Female': female}, 
                    index = np.arange(1, 11))
df['Mean'] = df[['Male', 'Female']].mean(axis = 1).round(1)
df
```

[Selecting the first two rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dSLb.png), works fine for method a and b

```
print('Method A: \n', df['Mean'][:2])
print('Method B: \n', df.loc[:2, 'Mean'])
```

```
Method A: 
1     7.5
2    12.5

Method B: 
1     7.5
2    12.5
```

But not for [selecting the last 2 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOG2V.png), it doesn't work the same. Method A returns the last two rows as it should.
Method B (.loc) doesn't, it returns the whole dataframe. Why is this and how do I fix it?

```
print('Method A: \n', df['Mean'][-2:])
print('Method B: \n', df.loc[-2:, 'Mean'])
```

```
Method A: 
9     11.5
10    14.5

Method B: 
1      7.5
2     12.5
3      9.0
4     11.5
5     16.0
6     13.5
7     13.0
8     12.5
9     11.5
10    14.5
```

Comment: Possibly because you should use `iloc` if you're using integer index positions in your slices. `loc` uses labels, not integer positions. *(There is no index **label** `-2`.)* [How are iloc and loc different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.index[-2:]` to get the index of the lasts two rows which are 9 and 10 instead of only `-2:`. Here is some reproducible code:

```
male = [6, 14, 12, 13, 21, 14, 14, 14, 14, 18]
female = [9, 11, 6, 10, 11, 13, 12, 11, 9, 11]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Male': male,
                    'Female': female}, 
                    index = np.arange(1, 11))
df['Mean'] = df[['Male', 'Female']].mean(axis = 1).round(1)

print('Method B: \n', df.loc[df.index[-2:], 'Mean'])
```

Output:

```
Method B: 
9     11.5
10    14.5
Name: Mean, dtype: float64
```

As you can see it returns the two last rows of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can get with `iloc` and `tail` method, like that :

```
df['Mean'][-2:]
df['Mean'].iloc[-2:]
df['Mean'].tail(2)
```

We don't usually use `loc` for this. `iloc` or other methods are easier to use. But if you want to use it could be like this:

```
df.loc[df.index[-2:],'Mean']
```