# Pandas reversing Data Frames giving strange results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reverse

Let's say I've a df

```
           value
2023-02-01     a
2023-02-02     b
2023-02-03     c
2023-02-04     d
```

when I try to reverse `df` and after doing some operations If i reverse back It not showing complete df Like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"value": {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d"}}
)
df.index = pd.date_range(start='2023-02-01', periods=4,freq='D')
new  = df.loc[::-1] #Reversing 1 time
new2 = new.loc[::-1] # Reversing back again..
print(new2)
```

Giving me # even though I haven't done any operations on df

```
2023-02-04     d
```

Expected

```
          value
2023-02-01     a
2023-02-02     b
2023-02-03     c
2023-02-04     d
```

Version Detials

```
Pandas 1.3.5
Python 3.9
```

Comment: What is your pandas version? for me working correctly. If change `loc` to `iloc` it working for you?

Comment: Try ```df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"value": {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d"}}
)
df.index = pd.date_range(start='2023-02-01', periods=4,freq='D')
new = df.loc[::-1]
df = new.loc[::-1]
print(df)```

Comment: Wow `iloc` working @jezrael .. Can I know why?

Comment: [loc vs iloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different#:~:text=The%20main%20distinction%20between%20the,or%20columns)%20at%20integer%20locations.)

Comment: Just my 2 cents. I am getting the same problem (pandas '1.4.3'). iloc works for me, also reset_index before second reverse works too.