# pandas SettingWithCopyWarning after trying .loc

Tags: python, pandas

First I build a new DataFrame frame. Then create a new frame2 by filtering some data from frame. Now I want to assign some value to frame2:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

frame = DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3)), index=['a', 'c', 'd'], columns=['Ohio', 'Texas', 'California'])
mask = frame['Texas'] > 1
print frame[mask]
frame2 = frame.loc[mask]
frame2.loc['c', 'Ohio'] = 'me'
print frame2
```

but I got this warning:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:461: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

why I keep got this warning although I used the recommended .loc syntax? what i supposed to do to avoid this warning?

Comment: it seems that i have found one possible solution at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688307/settingwithcopywarning-even-when-using-loc. does someone have other good ideas?

Comment: What is your intention here? do you want to update a copy or the original df

Comment: @EdChum i want to update the copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing

```
frame2 = frame.loc[mask]
```

to

```
frame2 = frame.loc[mask].copy()
```

eliminates this warning.